# Heroku Django ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Tags: python, django, heroku, valueerror

I keep getting `ValueError` when running migrate on Heroku. 
My django application works with no problems locally. From what I can see I think the problem is with this model, but I can't find what it could be. Specially because running `makemigrations` and migrate locally works just fine.

The error I get: (note: only on heroku when running: `heroku run python manage.py migrate`)

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ nameless-sands-... up, run.1867 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, narocilnice, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying narocilnice.0012_auto_20170808_1312...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 215, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 515, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 112, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 613, in _alter_field
    new_default = self.effective_default(new_field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 229, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 770, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 762, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1853, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed 0012_auto_20170808_1312.py file, there was line when integer filed had default = "-". I deleted it. But I still don't know why locally this was not a problem?

Comment: Are you using the same database locally as on heroku?

Comment: My best guess is that the default value was something else when you did run it locally, either by user input during makemigrations or that the file differed. The ValueError is valid and should be raised locally on the same migration file if the DBMS is the same.